# unable to use scanf twice for scanning a string and then scanning a char

Tags: c, stdin, scanf

I tried using `scanf` twice for scanning a string and then scanning a char. It scans string first and does not execute the second `scanf`. When I use both `%s` and `%c` in a single `scanf` it works perfectly. Can you tell me why this happens?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char s[100],ch;
scanf("%s",s);
scanf("%c",&ch);   //this does not work
printf("%s %c",s,ch);
return 0;
}
```

another program which works

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char s[100],ch;
scanf("%s %c",s,&ch);  //this works!
printf("%s %c",s,ch);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Does not work" does not explain to us what is happening. What did you expect to happen? What actually happened? What have you done to try and understand the problem? What happened when you used a debugger with the program?

Comment: In the first option, put a breakpoint immediately after the second `scanf` and check the value of `ch`. Most likely it's the newline character from the first `scanf`. Don't refrain from learning how to debug your code, it will help you in the future.

Comment: Note: avoid naked `"%s"`.  Better to use `"%99s"` here.

Answer (score 4):

Please add a space before `%c` in `scanf()`.

There is a newline character after the string is read so this is being taken by `%c`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char s[100],ch;
scanf("%s",s);
scanf(" %c",&ch);   
printf("%s %c",s,ch);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another, logically more obvious (IMO) way to clear the leftover newline character from scanf is to add %*c after the formatter for the input -- so you'd `scanf ("%s%*c", s);` in the fragment above; that clears the buffer so the next scanf call won't read the newline left in the buffer by the previous one.  The * after % in the format entry tells scanf to discard the scanned value (for any format).