# 2nd Scanf in loop is not being read.jumps to else condition

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, switch-statement

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"


#define A_P 4.55

double pounds;
double subT = 0.0;
double totalP = 0.0;
double totalSub = 0.0;

void main()
{
char item;

    while (1) {
        printf("Please select your item.\n");
        scanf("%c", &item);
        if (item == 'a') {
            price = A_P;
            printf("Please enter the amount in pounds.(lb)");
            scanf("%f", &pounds);
            if (pounds > 0) {
                subT = price * pounds;
                totalP += pounds;
                totalSub += subT;
            }
            else {
                printf("1st");
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("2nd");
        }

    }
```

I don't understand why i am getting this logical error. When the user enters an item, i ask the user for another input which is the "pounds" of the item. But i have no idea why it goes to the last else condition which prints out "2nd". Can anyone explain what is happening. I initially tried this with a switch as well but the same problem occurs.

```
case 'A':
        case 'a':
            price = A_P;
            printf("Please enter the amount in pounds.(lb)");
            scanf("%f", &pounds);
            if (pounds > 0) {
                subT = price * pounds;
                totalP += pounds;
                totalSub += subT;
            }
            else
                Beep(500, 500);
            break;
```

...

```
default:// goes straight to the defualt statement ignores second scanf which reads pounds varaible
            printf("That is an invlalid input.\n");
            Beep(500, 1000);
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", &item);` --> `scanf(" %c", &item);`  (add space)  Else on 2nd loop, `item` has the value of `'\n'`

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945123/unable-to-use-scanf-twice-for-scanning-a-string-and-then-scanning-a-char

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: function skips user input in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441501/c-function-skips-user-input-in-code)

Comment: *Always* check return value of `scanf`. It's pointless to debug IO code which does not detect "normal" error conditions. This is doubly important with `scanf` as it can have parse errors in addition to the usual IO errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `scanf()` in the second iteration of the loop is "consuming" the `\n` from the first iteration. This is why `scanf()` doesn't prompt you the second time and automatically goes to the "2nd" condition. chux is right--you can fix this by adding a space before the `%c`:

```
scanf(" %c", &item);
```

For more information, see this thread: [Using the scanf function in while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911923/using-the-scanf-function-in-while-loop)

Side note: it doesn't look like you're declaring the `price` variable anywhere. You also should use `%lf` instead of `%f` for the `scanf()` taking in the double.